# How to prevent the trigger of django signals based Field value of Model?

Tags: django, django-signals

I have a model with a boolean field. Based on the value of this boolean field I want to trigger a post_save signal in django. How can I implement it?

Answer (score 2):

So in the signal you set conditionals to check for the value of that boolean field and then perform whatever action you need.
For example:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def perform_action(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # You can remove the if created clause if you want this across board whether updating or creating
    if created:
        if instance.boolean_field==True: # Check here
             # Perform action here
        else:
            pass
```